# Disable vibrancy inside of a NSScrollView on Mojave?

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, macos-mojave

`NSScrollView` seems to now add a vibrancy effect layer behind the content view. This is causing problems with some custom non-opaque views and I'd rather not mess with their opacity and tweak background drawing etc. Is there a way to disable this new behavior on Mojave?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the issue? I wonder if it's the same that I experienced some time ago.

Comment: @strangetimes: What was the outcome of this ?

Comment: @MarcT. I ended up adding a dirty hack to hide the vibrancy effect layer behind the content view. There seems to be no other reliable way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a `NSTableView` or `NSOutlineView` in the `NSScrollView` it should be enough to set Highlight from `NSTableView` or `NSOutlineView` in Interface Builder from "Source List" to "Regular" on "None"

[image]

Comment: That isn't an option unfortunately as selecting "Source List" introduces its own quirks.